# Does phpMyAdmin have built in security

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I want to know when creating a database on phpMyAdmin does the site automatically create protection for attacks like sql injection? And if it does can this be turned off? I am using the phpMyAdmin which comes with MAMP if that helps clear things up.

Comment: A short answer to this: no. You have to code your protection in your scripts.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a client application for MySQL, it does not interfere with your application and the queries you write.You still need to make sure your code is safe.if you want you can look for a web framework that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, phpMyAdmin properly escapes your queries so you can name a table something like `x'; DROP TABLE users; --` and it will actually create the table. As Sam D says, your application, on the other hand, is another matter entirely and has nothing to do with phpMyAdmin, so make sure you're properly managing user input in your application.

No, it can't be turned off from within phpMyAdmin (is there a reason why would you want that?).